# Limit of compostion of sequences

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

how do we approach composition of sequences and their limit. One example $a_n=(1-1/n)^{n^2}$ would be $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}(1-1/n)^{n^2}$ as $(1-1/n)^n $ goes to to $1/e$ can we conclude that as $1/e<1$ the sequence goes to 0?

THANK YOUR FOR THE REMARK. It should be $(1-1/n)^n $ goes to to $1/e$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $(1-1/n)^{n^2}$ can be written as $(1-1/n)^{n×n}$, and so, given that $\lim_{n\to \infty}(1-1/n)^n=e^{-1}$, you get that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}(1-1/n)^{n^2}=\lim_{n\to \infty}(1-1/n)^{n×n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}e^{-n} \to 0$$

Comment: thats wrong. $(1-1/n)^n$ converges to $1/e$

Comment: @Maths mmh you are right, I'll edit. Hope this time it will be correct

Answer (score 0):

$$a_n=\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}\implies \log(a_n)=n^2 \log\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)$$ Using Taylor expansion
$$\log(a_n)=n^2\left(-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right) \right)=-n-\frac{1}{2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
$$a_n=e^{\log(a_n)}\sim \frac{e^{-n}}{\sqrt{e}}$$

Using a calculator for $n=10$, the exact answer is
$$a_{10}=\left(\frac 9 {10}\right)^{100}=0.00002656$$ while the approximation gives ${e^{-21/2}}=0.00002754$